# How to get phone number?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, validation, sms

Basically I would like to program an app which is able **to get the phone number of this device** it is running on. I know that simply "reading" the phone number from a contact-fetch-list is not possible and meanwhile it is not compatible with the AppStore guidelines.

Still, I'm sure there's an option to fetch the phone number from an app.

---

Unfortunately, a simple SMS validation does not seem to make sense to me because this scenario could come up:

- User XY has two cell phones with different numbers (Cell A, Cell B)
- User XY logs in on the phone A with the phone number of phone B and enters the code which was sent to the device B on the phone A.
- His number is confirmed, but the number on the mobile B now belongs to mobile A. -> This is wrong and may not be so.

I thought of a combination of UUID (readable with Swift) and a confirmation SMS but I have to be honest: So far, I have come up with no working method.

---

**Note**: I chose to post the question on SO because none of the other forums have a real affiliation with Swift (in my opinion). I hope somebody can help me a bit on how to develop a working method to get the telephone number of a device based on Swift.

This is what is given:

```
func getDeviceUUID() -> String {
    return UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
}

sendSMSToNumber(number: String, validationCode: String)
```

**Edit**: How is it possible for messengers like e.g. WhatsApp to verify the phone number matching to your device?

Comment: Why is the `A + B` scenario you describe a problem? You verified the user XY has control over the phone number `B`.

Comment: Yes true. But I'd like to know (like I've mentioned above) which device is connected to which phonenumber. @luk2302

Comment: "How is it possible for messengers like e.g. WhatsApp to verify the phone number matching to your device?" - they don't, they don't prevent the scenario you described. (at least they did not do that like a year ago)

Comment: Apple takes privacy seriously. You can not obtain the user's phone number except by asking them to tell you. You can check that the number isn't already registered in your database before sending the validation and if they give you the right code you have to assume that that is their number